# Liskov Substitution Principle and Redundant Methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

I have an interface called IRepository. This interface defines a set of generic methods such as:

```
 IQueryable<T> Get<T>() where T : class;
 void Add<T>(T obj) where T : class;
 void Update<T>(T obj) where T : class;
 void SaveChanges();
```

I then have a class which implements this interface. This class actually uses Entity Framework to implement these methods. However the method update is redundant as the Entity Framework tracks changes made to entities retrieved so I just get the entity I want, update it then call SaveChanges. However in the future I may want to replace this concrete implementation of IRepository with something else. Which probably won't track changes like Entity framework does. So I'm thinking I want to leave the update method in the interface, but in my concrete implementation of this interface just leave the method in but doing nothing. e.g.

```
public void Update<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
}
```

This seems to fit with the Liskov Substitution Principle, I can replace the implementation of the interface with something else. It's just that somethings might not need to actually implement all the methods defined on the interface.

Is this a good approach. I was thinking this was okay maybe even mark the method as obsolete in the implementation of IRepository stating why it is obsolete in this implementation.

It just seems a bit odd having an update method which does nothing and having this called all over the application even though it doesn't actually do anything. But then if we changed the implemenation of IRepository, to an implmentation that does need an update method then we can substitute this in with no code changes required.

Comment: That's a bit orthogonal to the question, but by abstracting out the abstraction (which EF already is), you're almost automatically losing a lot of power that comes with it (caching, both first and second level if you introduce one, change tracking etc)...

Comment: Nice to read: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/ and this: http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92

Comment: Very interesting read it describes exactly the interface I have come up with. I guess an interface like this does makes false guarantees. Not all queries will be guranteed to work if I replace the implementation.

Comment: Patryk I agree that I'm abstracting out an abstraction but I wanted to keep all dependencies to EF in the one place so it's more decoupled. This way if I change from EF I only have to change the one class, not everywhere that database access is required. I still benefit from change tracking etc as the actual implementation is EF? If I did not abstract this I would have EF specific code scattered through the application?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, having a method on a an interface that is not implemented in most situations tells me that the scope of the interface is too wide.

You could remove the update method from the base repository interface and add it alone to an IUpdatableRepository that inherits from the base interface. You concrete classes that need to update can then implement the IUpdatableRepository interface instead.

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but you get the point...

Comment: Good point on the scope of the interface. I like your suggestion.

Comment: Given the limitations of many frameworks' type systems, the optimal level of interface subdivision is often different from what it would be without such limitations.  If different objects do different combinations of X, Y, and Z, even if few do all of them, using a "kitchen sink" interface, along with a property that reports *in detail* what features an instance supports, may be cleaner than having to define a different interface type for every *combination* of features that might be implemented, use run-time type-checks and downcasts all over the place, or both.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have a single implementation which you've wrapped in an interface. LSP isn't the only thing to worry about in design: I would argue that [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) are more fundamental, whereas LSP is only a way of keeping things simple and predictable in an object oriented design. Trying to design for **any** conceivable future change in your system will actually tend to make your system **harder** to change due to increased complexity. Are you reasonably likely to replace your repository with an alternate implementation which needs the Update method? Then by all means, retain it. If it's only a possibility, strip it out right now (and, possibly, consider using EF directly).

After all, "You can solve every problem by adding another layer of abstraction, except too many layers of abstraction."

Comment: I fully agree with KISS and YAGNI being fundamental. However I do worry about calling EF directy. The EF component of the system is easily decoupled by abstracting this. Then if anything were to change in this area, code changes would be restricted to the one area not throughout the whole application. I don't see this as adding much complexity for such a gain? Also what about Unit Testing I need to abstract this data access component so I can test my code in isolation?